# Could not find or load main class in fat/uber jar

Tags: java, ant, executable-jar

I have java project which has spring dependencies. I am building a jar file via ANT as shown below

```
<jar jarfile="Test.jar">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.karthik.EntryPoint"/>
    </manifest> 
    <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" includes="**" />
</jar>
```

When I run the command  **java -jar Test.jar**. I get an error as shown below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

To resolve this, I created a fat/uber jar which has all spring dependencies as shown below :

```
<jar jarfile="Test.jar">    
     <zipgroupfileset dir="${build.dir}/lib" includes="spring*.jar" />  

     <manifest>
         <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.karthik.EntryPoint"/>
     </manifest>    

     <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" includes="**" />
     <fileset dir="${src.java.dir}" includes="**/*.java" />
</jar>
```

I can now see spring classes bundled in Test.jar.
 But when I run the command **java -jar Test.jar**, I get an error as shown below

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.karthik.EntryPoint
```

Why am I getting this error only in uber/fat jar and how do we resolve it?

Comment: Request anyone to please help me resolve this error.